# Importing from parent folder to child in proto

Tags: import, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm trying to import the proto defn from parent proto into the child proto with following folder structure.

```
|
|--parent.proto
|
|--sub
    |--child.proto
```

**parent.proto**

```
message Attribute {
  ---
}
```

**child.proto**

```
import "parent.proto"

    message Child {
      int32 attributeNo = 1;
      com.model.Attribute attribute = 2;

    }
```

Currently it's giving me error saying it couldn't found the parent.proto.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

`protoc` looks for its imports in the directories specified using an `-I` flag. For example, you could add `-I/home/user/my_awesome_proto_lib` to the `protoc` command line args, and the compiler would look for your imports there.

From the help page of protoc, about the `--proto_path`:

```
  -IPATH, --proto_path=PATH   Specify the directory in which to search for
                              imports.  May be specified multiple times;
                              directories will be searched in order.  If not
                              given, the current working directory is used.
```

So currently, when you're running `protoc` it will look for `parent.proto` in the `sub` directory. This is obviously not what you need. You could change your import to `import "../parent.proto"` which would go back to the root level and grab `parent.proto` from there. But the generally encouraged style in protobuf is not to use relative imports.

Instead, you could consider adding the root of your proto project as an `-I`/`--proto_path` flag.

Another option would be to compile your proto files from the root of the project. You could `cd` to the root directory of the project and `protoc` from there.