# Importing Protofile from a different path

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I am trying to import a Proto file into another one from a different folder and haven't been successful in doing so. Here's the scenario:

I have a .Proto in folder ....\abc\protos\ProtoA.proto and another one in folder ....\def\protos\ProtoB.proto.

I need ProtoA to import ProtoB but it's in a different folder and using Import "....\def\protos\ProtoB.proto" doesn't work because it doesn't like "...." in the path.

What are the steps i need to follow to import the file in correctly from a different path?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53128417/11810946) your question? You can either set `proto_path` to the common base folder or specify `proto_path` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing and I'm unsure whether it's effectively explained in the docs.

Proto file imports are absolute to the proto package **and** the package structure must be preserved in the filing system structure.

However, the absolute disk location is only important when using `protoc` per @Brits comment so that the compiler can find the protos.

So.... Your import for  `....\def\protos\ProtoB.proto` should reflect the specific package and service or method or message name that you're importing *not* its disk location (which is what you're using).

Then, when you `protoc`, you should `--proto_path` and give (I think absolute not relative) paths to the filing system locations that contain the protos needed to be imported.

Have a look at [`Any`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/any.proto) by way of example.

In a proto, you `import "google.protobuf.Any"`, it's package plus the message name.

When you `protoc` it, `Any` is often already in the include path but, if it weren't, you'd need to `--proto_path=/path/to/foo` if `foo` is the root directory containing `google/protobuf/any.proto`; the proto file must be in a directory called `protobuf` in a directory called `google` for the import to work.

If you're familiar with Golang and `GOPATH`, this mirrors how Go packages are named by their directory (not file) name and referenced locally by their location being in the `GOPATH`; it's now different with Go Modules.

Comment: So, I'm doing all this in C# project. Isn't protoc specifically for Java/C++? I have a proto file stored in my solution and it's being referenced in a .NET Standard project. The other proto file that I am bringing in is stored in a relative path elsewhere and doing this does not help: syntax = "proto3";
import "..\..\Document Managemet\Protos\PrintTargetType.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
option csharp_namespace = "Instec.Services.Forms.Messages.Grpc";
package instec.services.formsmessages;

Comment: Some other language implementations do implement `protoc` directly. IIRC C# does this too. Unfortunately, I don't use Visual Studio (?) and so am unable to help resolve configuration issues. I think there must be somewhere in the project configuration that you can enumerate the directories contain the packages that contain your protobufs. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422186/importing-proto-files-from-another-project